# Converting SVG files: Exception running shell command

Tags: android

I'm using Figma to design a simple page to convert it into composable function using Relay. I've linked the Figma project to android studio, but when I debug the project in android studio I have this error:

> Converting SVG files: Exception running shell command 'C:\Users\example\AndroidStudioProjects\example\app\build\tmp\com.google.relay\0.3.00\vd-tool\bin\vd-tool.bat'.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

These are the [Figma Prerequisites](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/relay/install-relay#prerequisites)
to use the plug-in in Android Studio

1. You must be signed into a Figma Account.
2. You have installed Android Studio 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox or higher.
3. You have installed the Java Runtime.

For me it was the 3rd one. I installed Java Runtime and my issues was resolved